# How to convert one generic list to another

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

```
public static List<IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_ResultCache> GetAllApps(bool initialized, string language)
{
    List<IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_ResultCache> objApp = new List<IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_ResultCache>();

    List<IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_Result> objApps = new List<IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_Result>();

    if (initialized == false)
    {
        var t = ListCopy(objApps, x => (IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_ResultCache)x); // Error
        objApp = admin.getAllAppsByLanguage(language).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
    }
}

public static List<TResult> ListCopy<TSource, TResult>(List<TSource> input, Func<TSource, TResult> convertFunction)
{
    return input.Select(x => convertFunction(x)).ToList();
}
```

> My Class

```
public class IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_ResultCache
{
    public long AppId { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string AppDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string AppDetails { get; set; }
    public string AppImageURL { get; set; }
    public byte[] AppImageData { get; set; }
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string AppCreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime AppCreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string AppModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AppModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> isDeleted { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> isPromotional { get; set; }
    public string GenderTarget { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> CountryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> StateId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> AgeLimitId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AppMinAge { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AppMaxAge { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

**I am trying to convert one generic class to another but getting this error**

Comment: Are IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_ResultCache and IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_Result classes are same?

Comment: yes they have the same properties but they are in different namespaces

Comment: List<T>.ConvertAll(TOutput) - See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_Result` and `IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_ResultCache` are different types and you cannot cast the first type to the other as you are doing in this statement:

```
var t = ListCopy(objApps, x => (IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_ResultCache)x);
```

If the types have the same structure you should probably just have one instead of two types. Otherwise you will have to copy the data from the first type to the other. E.g.:

```
var t = ListCopy(objApps, x => new IndianAppStore_GetAllAppsByLanguage_ResultCache {
  AppId = x.AppId,
  AppName = x.AppName,
  ...
});
```

This becomes tedious very quickly and one option is to use a library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to automate the process.